# How can I evaluate algebraic expressions defined in YAML?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I have the following two separate YAML files.

- `val.yaml`: variables are defined here
- `expr.yaml`: expressions are defined here

**`val.yaml`**

```
x: 2
y: 3
z: 5
```

**`expr.yaml`**

```
result: (x + y) * z
```

**`parse.py`**

```
import yaml

with open('val.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    val = yaml.load(stream)

with open('expr.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    expr = yaml.load(stream)

....

# this should be (2 + 3) * 5 = 25
print expr['result']
```

How can I evaluate expressions defined in `expr.yaml` by referencing variables defined in `val.yaml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most easily do this with `sympy`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import ruamel.yaml
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
with open('var.yaml') as stream:
    vars = yaml.load(stream)
with open('expr.yaml') as stream:
    expr = yaml.load(stream)

for k in expr:
    l = parse_expr(expr[k], vars)
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, l))
```

which prints (using Python 2 or 3):

```
result: 25
```

- You should really start using `print` as a function, even if you are stuck with Python 2.7, hence the `from __future__` import. Python 2.7 with its print statement is planned to be end-of-life in two years, so use such forward compatibility imports and get accustomed to using them.
- you should not be using PyYAML's `yaml.load()` as it can be unsafe, certainly if someone else edits your input files. Either use `yaml.safe_load()` or use the above (which loads faster as well).

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing it, even if I **strongly** discourage this approach in a production situation (`eval` should be avoided, input should be sanitized, etc...). The idea is to perform s substitution, iterating over the variables in the yaml, under the hypothesis that the expression yaml (in `result`) follows the same naming convention. Here a sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml

VARS_YAML = """
x: 2
y: 3
z: 5
"""

EXPR_YAML = """
result: (x + y) * z
"""

vars = yaml.load(VARS_YAML)
expr = yaml.load(EXPR_YAML)

for key, value in vars.items(): # for python2: vars.iteritems()
  expr['result'] = expr['result'].replace(key, str(value))

r = eval(expr['result'])
print(r) # for python2: print r
# => 25
```

This code is for python-3 (the only version I have available at the moment), but it is simple to move it to python-2 (that I think is your version). If you prefer to load the yaml from a file:

```
with open('var.yaml', 'r') as var_file:
  vars = yaml.load(var_file)
```

is more than enough.